# GoLand using delve to remote debug RPI

Tags: go, raspberry-pi, remote-debugging, goland, delve

I am running Jetbrains Goland on my MacBook Air M1. Debugging locally is no problem.  Im writing an app to run on a Raspberry Pi. I have it setup where it will compile and run the app remotely on the RPI using a standard run configuration with the env variables in the run configuration set to GOOS=linux;GOARCH=arm;GOARM=5.

Now I want to debug remotely as well.  When I run the debug configuration, it compiles and copys over to the RPI fine.  It also copies over dlv just fine, so my RPI doesnt have to have it loaded there.  However, the dlv it is copying over was not built for the RPI, it was built for my Mac.

In the JetBrains documentation I found this:

> Compile Delve with the same Go version, host and target as your application because there might be slight differences between the various operating systems, which could cause the debugging session not to work as expected.

Im not even sure where JetBrains keeps its copy of dlv that it is currently copying over.
But how do I compile a version of dlv that will run on my RPI and how do I tell GoLand to use that version of dlv instead of what it is using now?

}Dan

Comment: Please see: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-10971/Remote-debugging-dlv-syntax-error#focus=Comments-27-4852093.0-0